# Postgresql type bytea not displaying text in html

Tags: python, html, django, postgresql

In my postgresql db i have the following fields:
[image]

Field O is of type bytea called "File" and X is called "Document_name". When I call for that column to be displayed in my html file, it shows what i think is hex format:

```
<tr>
    <td>{{ item.Document_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.File }}</td>
</tr>

test                <memory at 0x7fecefe9e1c8>
Document_name       <memory at 0x7fecefe9e288>
Document_name       <memory at 0x7fecefe9e348>
Document_name       <memory at 0x7fecefe9e408>
Proposal Document   <memory at 0x7fecefe9e588>
test                <memory at 0x7fecefe9e4c8>
```

How do I make it so it displays the text I see in my DB e.g. User_storeis_for_PTK.docx instead of memory at 0x7fecefe9e288

Comment: what if you print them in the console ?

Comment: I get non string error